# Why when I run application it just skip some ifs

Tags: autohotkey

As I said text that is bolded doesn't work, it just skip it (it worked without those ifs) could you help me? Please, I'm doing that few hours but it still doesn't work. I tried to add this if not in this loop and it worked, please give me a hand, I spent so much time
on it  ;(

````
Gui, Add, CheckBox, x405 y317 w15 h15 vwyrzucaniediax gZapisz,
Gui, Show, h500 w800, Skrypt Na Kopanie
Return

Zapisz:
Gui, Submit , NoHide
return

F8::
WinMove, Minecraft, , , , 1280, 720
sleep 1000
Loop
{
    if poziome
    {

    }

    if pionowe
    {

    }

    Checker()
}



Checker()
{
    x := 503
    y := 385
    l := 0
    i := 0
    Send e
    loop, 27{
    if(i = 9){
    i := 0
    l++
    }
    Sleep 100
    MouseMove, x +36*i, y + 36*l

    **if wyrzucaniediax // all strong text is just skipped idk why
    {
        Dropdiax()
    }
    **

    i++
    }
    Send e
    Sleep 50
}

dropdiax(){
    diaxcolor := 0x80ĄFFE
    color:= getColor()
    if(color == diaxcolor){
        Send {LCtrl down}
        Send q
        Sleep 50
        Send {LCtrl up}
    }
}```
````

Comment: What are you trying to do with that `If`? `wyrzucaniediax` is not defined, so it evaluates to `False`.

Comment: It is defined, just not in that function's scope.

Answer (score 1):

Your `wyrzucaniediax` variable (maybe you could use better variable names when asking for help?) isn't defined in that function's scope.
To tell the function you're using a variable from outside of its scope, you can use the [`Global`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#Global) keyword.

```
Checker()
{
    global wyrzucaniediax 
    x := 503
    y := 385
    l := 0
```